# javascript or jquery regxp

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to get ID from given value with JavaScript or jQuery. Value is `"name (id)"`, name can be `"a-zA-Z0-9._"` and id only number.

For example it can be

```
test (123)
   or
test_456.123 (456)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you share any code that you have tried, please?

Comment: Do you really need a regular expression? Split on whitespace and take the last element. Or split on parentheses and take the penultimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option (with regex):

```
var str = "test_456.123 (456)",
    id = (str.match(/\((\d+)\)$/) || []).pop();

console.log(id);  // "456"
```

Another option (without regex):

```
var str = "test_456.123 (456)",
    id = parseInt(str.split("(").pop(), 10);

console.log(id);  // 456
```

Answer (score 1):

regex: `/([a-zA-Z0-9\._]+)\ (\(\d+\))/`

Answer (score 1):

```
var id = value.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9._]+\(([0-9]+)\)/gi, "$1")
```